# how to get all IDs from a sqlite database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database manager class where i build a table that has two columns.  the first column being an integer, and i am trying to write a method that will return all values in that column as a list:

```
public List<Integer> getAllStyleIDs(){
        List<Integer> results = null;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "select * from " + DBConstants.allStyles;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                results.add(cursor.getInt(0));


            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();

        return results;
    }
```

but i am getting a null point exception

any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the LogCat output when the error occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list `results` is null, then you attempt to add to it. Try this:

```
List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing: the list hasn't been initialized.
Second thing: using raw queries is not recommended:

Try something like this:

```
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    this.database = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String [] columns = {_ID}; // name of the column

    Cursor cursor = this.database.query(COURSES_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    int iId = cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);

    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        Integer rowId = cursor.getInt(iName);
        results.add(rowId);
    }

    cursor.close();
    this.database.close();

    return results;
```